# Disable authentication while server startup in glassfish

Tags: authentication, glassfish, solaris

When starting up domain in *sunglassfish v2.1.1* in **solaris**, am prompted to enter admin user name, admin user password and master password.

Is there a way to disable the prompt and do the startup?

TIA
Banu
glassfish user

Answer (score 1):

The master password is the password to the keystore in glassfish/domains/domainX/config/

**Store the master password in a file** (gf docs recommend against this, I think they mean for a production machine): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4332/6nfq988p5/index.html

```
glassfish/bin/asadmin change-master-password --domain-dir domain1 --savemasterpassword=true
```

**Store the admin password in a file:**
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4332/6nfq988uv/index.html

```
glassfish/bin/asadmin login --host localhost --port 4848
```

Also look at creating a password alias for production machines: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4332/6nfq988qe/index.html

```
glassfish/bin/create-password-alias --interactive=true --host=localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile .asadmin_password
```

For production machines, secure the directory where you store the passwords (i.e. the user home directory you're logged into).